# installing Pyside in Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyside

I tried installing Pyside on Windows 7 64 with python 2.7.8 using :

```
pip install PySide
```

and everything went fine and I ran a **helloworld** program in that.

Now in my home PC, Windows 7 32 bit and python 2.7.8. I tried the same,now its showing 
`error : MSVC version 9 not found`

I didnt had any such problems when installing the same to a fresh Windows 7 64 bit (Case 1) and I am very sure that in that I dont have any Visual C compilers or visual studio. What can be the possible reasons??.

Comment: PySide windows binaries are distributed as wheel packages and older pip versions don't support the wheel binary package format out-of-the box. Ensure that you have latest pip installed on your home pc.

Comment: @rlacko:thanks its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest version of [`pip`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Goto Python scripts folder , open a command window there and then

```
pip install -U PySide
```